# What is the right term for students admitted to the school in previous years, if you are also a student? Do you call them "elder students"?

Tags: terminology

Say I am a third year student. I find myself frequently need to refer to "some student" in their fourth year and fifth year. For example,

"A student of higher year than me" helped me with project.

What is the right term to replace those in the quotes?

If you guys know Chinese, there is simple term for this purpose, "xue zhang" or "xue jie". However, I seem not able to identify a corresponding term in English.

Thanks!

Comment: What do the students at the school call them? There is bound to be a local tradition, and they supercede normal rules.

Comment: Maybe "older student." But we don't really use this. We'd be more likely to say "I received help with [specific part of project] from [name], a junior (or "third-year student") in the [Department name] Department"

Comment: If you were in the first couple of years I would suggest "upperclassman".   But that's an imprecise term if you're in the third year or such.

Comment: I'd just say a student was a year or two ahead of me, unless here was a reason to be precise.

Comment: What @JohnLawler said. *Ask them.*

Comment: Definitely, "older" not "elder." "Elder" often means somebody much older, who might have left the school 20 or 40 years ago, and the usual was to describe for such people is "alumni" (borrowed from Latin), not "elder students".

Comment: In Australia you could state the level the student is studying at and say you got help "from a student in year twelve" (or "eleven" or "ten" as may be the case). An "older" student usually means in a higher class, and a "senior" student usually means someone in their last few years of school.

Comment: I'd like to point out, except for "x years ahead" none of the answers here will be universal. Education systems vary a lot even between English speaking countries. Words like "Sophomore" etc are not likely to be understood outside the US.

My next point is based on an assumption but I suspect the term you are looking for is based on showing respect to older students. At least in my culture this doesn't exist, all students are on the same level and since language flows from culture there is no term at least in my version of english for what you are looking for.

Comment: 'senior' has a formal meaning in US contexts, but elsewhere it can be used colloquially to mean 'any student more senior than myself'

Comment: I agree with @Strawberry. If the US school system hadn't used it to refer to students in a specific grade, "senior" would have been perfect. Note that this still works outside of a educational context, e.g. in a professional context (but even there, ambiguity can also arise, e.g. if you're working in a retirement home)

Comment: The Japanese term "senpai" is familiar enough among certain groups that they'd know what you meant, but probably not advisable in a general audience.

Comment: @alephzero You seem to be describing _elderly_ there. _Elder_ refers to the older part in a specific comparison between (usually) two people or groups (the elder vs the younger); _elderly_ just means ‘old/aged’ in general.

Comment: "I got help from a 4th year student" should work in continental Europe.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The word used in my experience is [**upperclassman**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/upperclassman). The dictionary definition is a student of the junior or senior year of either high school or college, but for new first-years, it is often extended to sophomores, juniors, and seniors.

Note that this word is not (politically correct) gender neutral, and so *may* be phased out in the next twenty years or so.

Comment: Just to clarify: the word as used historically and in common use today -- absolutely *is* gender neutral grammatically. But there are social, political, and/or linguistic reasons that other terms may be preferred by some. (For example, "upperclassmate" is a probably less controversial alternative.)

Comment: "Man" was traditionally used as a gender neutral term for people... in the sense that traditionally women were not really considered to be people, they were property.  In other words, it was never really gender neutral.

Comment: @wjl Surely upperclassmate implies that you actually had a class together, which I don't think "upperclassman" does.

Comment: @wjl I added "politically correct" to mean more what I was trying to say. I agree with Casey that upperclassmate does not mean the same thing.

Comment: My undergraduate university used "upper division students" and "lower division students" rather than "upper/lower classmen", way back in the 1990s. It doesn't work very well to distinguish between 1st year students and everyone else or between juniors and seniors, though.

Comment: @1006a At my university, upper/lower division referred to a classification of credit. You'd get upper-division credit or lower-division credit depending on the course you were taking, not on your class standing.

Comment: @industry7 That is incorrect. _Man_ was historically used used as a gender-neutral term for people **because it meant ‘human being’**. It referred to women just as much as to men. The narrowing down of its meaning to only refer to males came later (when it ousted the original word for ‘male human’, _wer_). At that point it stopped being gender-neutral as a standalone count noun, though it remained fairly gender-neutral in many other senses. The perception that words like _mankind_ are not gender-neutral is of recent date.

Answer (score 14):

*x* "year(s) ahead of" me
*y* "year(s) behind" me

> He is fond of casually dropping the names of his drama school contemporaries. Ewan McGregor, Joseph Fiennes ('We would potter next door to see Ralph playing leads at the RSC'), and more long-term friends such as Dominic West, whom he knows from his Eton days. 'Dom was a couple of **years ahead of** me,' Lewis recalls.

[from The Telegraph](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/culture/tvandradio/9051874/Soldiering-on-Damian-Lewis-in-Homeland.html)

> President Obama was four **years ahead of** me at Harvard law school....

[quoted in The Atlantic](https://www.theatlantic.com/politics/archive/2013/02/ted-cruz-sees-communists/318061/)

> That reminds me: Lee Harvey Oswald, a **year or two behind** me in school, lived in Covington in those days.

[from the New York Times](http://www.nytimes.com/1972/07/23/archives/they-dont-make-picture-shows-like-that-any-more.html)

> Prince Harry had started at Sandhurst in May 2005 and was a **year ahead of** his older brother.

[from the Evening Standard](https://www.standard.co.uk/news/uk/prince-williams-career-from-sandhurst-to-the-raf-8811843.html)

variant:

> My favorite Stanford summer was 1979, when a woman engineer in the class **ahead of** me helped me get a summer job at Chase Manhattan Bank in NYC.

[Stanford University website](http://web.stanford.edu/dept/OOD/communications/summerchallenge/index.html)

Comment: This is what I've heard most often in the mid-Atlantic US. Followed by "upperclassmen".

Comment: In the UK you'd use "above" and "below" rather than "ahead" and "behind". Or colloquially: "Someone in the year above helped me"

Answer (score 9):

In the United States, we would say the following:

- **Freshmen** (first year)
- **Sophomore** (second year)
- **Junior** (third year)
- **Senior** (fourth year)

The following terms work both for high school and college, both of which are typically four years. In other English speaking countries, they would usually just say **first year**, **second year**, etc. Even in some American Universities, this is becoming more common as fewer students complete their degrees in four years as is traditional. Personally, I went to a school where the typical degree took five years, so we used the term **middler** to describe a third year student, while **junior** and **senior** described a fourth and fifth year respectively.

Additionally, for simply contrasting two students of different years, you could say **lowerclassman** and **upperclassman**. The former refers to a first or second year student, while the later refers to a third or fourth year student.

Comment: I would rearrange your answer to emphasize **upperclassman** more. That is the more direct answer to the OP's question. As you say yourself, the US system isn't that widely applicable.

Comment: Neither the first group of suggestions (Freshmen/Sophomore/Junior/Senior) nor the second group of suggestions (lowerclassman/upperclassman) convey the "of year higher than me" that the OP asked for. Just because a student is a Senior doesn't mean he or she has more school years than I do, because I might be a Senior too. Likewise, the subject might be an upperclassman, but I might be too, so the term fails to convey that they have more school years than I do.

Comment: @Rainbolt If you're both seniors, then the other person doesn't have more years. You could be a junior and the other person a senior, and then you'd both be upperclassmen, but then you could just say "senior". If you're a sophomore, you can use "upperclassmen". If you're a freshman and you want to compare to a group that includes upperclassmen and sophomores, then you're stuck. I might just say "non-freshmen" in that case.

Comment: And if you're not in high school, then it would be "a fifth grader", "an eighth grader", and so on...

Comment: @ToddWilcox But what if you don't know my school year? If I say "A senior helped me with my project." then will you understand the person who helped me is of a higher school year than I am? I could say "I am a junior, and a senior helped me with my project." but that's not really a term.

Comment: @ToddWilcox I agree that without any context "upperclassman" usually means "junior" or "senior", but in some contexts, "upperclassman" just means "someone in a higher year than me", such as: "I was having trouble, but an upperclassman helped me" (a freshman referring to a sophomore) would be totally understandable and acceptable.

Comment: @wjl It would be understandable, but without further context I believe most would assume that the student was a Junior or a Senior, not a Sophomore.

Answer (score 7):

If I were saying that another student helped me with something, I wouldn't consider it important to mention whether that student was of a higher year, a lower year, or the same year. Maybe this could be considered a bit of a cultural difference.

If, for some reason, I did consider it important to identify the year of the student who helped me, I'd be more likely to do it by identifying the grade level (e.g. "a tenth-grader helped me") or by using the terms "freshman", "sophomore", "junior", or "senior" if those terms are applicable. But I still generally wouldn't emphasize the relationship between that student's year and my own.

In a pinch, I could say something like "an older student" or "a more senior student", but those strike me as phrases characteristic of more formal or clinical speech. It's just not something I would include without a strong reason to do so.

Answer (score 5):

There are often regional names for students of specific years (the most common in the United States being freshman, sophomore, junior, and senior for 1st, 2nd, 3rd, and 4th year of a four year program, respectively). For a more general term, I would typically say, "A more senior student" or "A more advanced student".

Comment: "A more advanced student" could work, but it might be a little bit ambiguous. (I think that term could also refer to a more gifted student, or one with a higher GPA, or one who had taken more honors classes, or one with a stronger academic background coming into a given program.)

Comment: Yes, that's a good point. A more senior student is probably less likely to be misinterpreted, but even that could technically also mean a student more advanced in age (but of the same year), though I would find that usage odd.

Comment: Although etymologically *senior* refers to age, its current use (at least in my idiolect - I'm from south-east England, FWIW) more typically refers to authority. I hear the noun phrase *senior management* more often than the only age-related one which comes to mind, *senior citizen* (the politically correct term for *old person*). As such, *more senior student* sounds odd to me: there's no hierarchy in the student body.

Answer (score 5):

In England you'd say " In the year above " for someone who's been there longer and " in the year below" for someone who's not been there as long as you - this is also sometimes express as an " upper " or " lower "

If your at university you'd generally refer to them by the year of their degree
"a Third year helped me figure out X" or " a graduate student helped me out"

its common in other areas of the world to use "upperclassman" and "lowerclassman"

Answer (score 2):

Just say "another student".  It should be enough, and it's *not* disrespectful to them in any way.  If you have to clarify, say something like "John help me with this project: he's in his fourth year."

I'm Korean, and my language also makes that distinction all the time.  When I joined a graduate program in the US, it took me some time to adjust: I'm a first-year student, here's another guy who joined two years ago, but we can be friends!  Unthinkable in Korea.

It is very unfortunate that my native language (and social custom) forces one to make such unnecessary distinction all the time, and it sounds like the Chinese language also does it to some degree, but for some reason, English does not have this particular problem, and there's no reason to import the unnecessary distinction into English.

(If I sound too preachy, consider a more neutral situation: imagine a language that makes distinction between male and female doctors, and one asking, "I want to say 'I went to see a doctor.', but I want to explain the doctor was female.  How do I make the distinction in English?"  The correct answer is: you don't, unless the doctor being female is somehow relevant, in which case you can simply say "The doctor was female, by the way.")

Answer (score 1):

In England, when I was at school, years were arranged as so:

- Year 1
- Year 2
- Year 3
- ...
- ...
- Year 10
- Year 11

Years 1 - 6 were at Primary School, and Years 7-11 were at Secondary School.

Then if the school had a Sixth Form:

- Year 12 (Sometimes called Lower Sixth)
- Year 13 (Sometimes called Upper Sixth)

If someone went to college instead (college is 16-18 typically in the UK, 18-21 is University) then you'd simply say they were in their xth year of college (i.e. 1st year, 2nd year)

As such, if I was in Year 10 and I wanted to talk about some a year above me, I might say:

> "A Year 11 helped me out with homework"

Or if I wanted to talk about an activity I did with someone a year below me

> "I played football with some Year 9s"